# Run a method from another class in Java

Tags: java, methods

What I am trying to do is run a method from another class, my `new Link().populateList();`. I've tried extending my Link class and a filling the `Link()` and `populateList()` with different parameters to no avail. Can anyone push me in the right direction? Here is my code down below:

Reverse.java Class having `main()` method

```
package main;

public class Reverse {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Link().populateList();
    }
}
```

Link.java

```
package main;

public class Link {
    public Link next;

    public String name;
    public int age;

    public Link(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void displayInformation(){
        System.out.println("Name: "+ name + ", Age: " + age);
    }

    public void populateList(){
        LinkedList people = new LinkedList();

        people.insertLinks("John", 21);
        people.insertLinks("David", 27);
        people.insertLinks("Abraham", 19);
    }
}
```

LinkedList.java

```
package main;

public class LinkedList {

    public Link first;

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return(first == null);
    }
    public void insertLinks(String name, int age){
        Link link = new Link(name, age);

        link.next = first;
        first = link;
    } 
    public void display(){
        Link link = first;

        while(link != null){
            link.displayInformation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that the `populateList` method is not run?

Comment: When I compile and run everything nothing happens.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? You haven't asked for anything to be printed. How would you know that "nothing happened"?

Comment: the code is a spagetti of many things

Comment: Something does happen. For example, in the method `populateList` you create a temporary list, populate it, and throw it away. That is not nothing, @Kevin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void populateList(){
    LinkedList people = new LinkedList();

    people.insertLinks("John", 21);
    people.insertLinks("David", 27);
    people.insertLinks("Abraham", 19);
}
```

The method *is* being run, but it doesn't do anything visible. It creates a linked list, adds three entries, and then throws the list away. It doesn't call `people.display()`, it doesn't `return people;`, nothing.